# Who calls /etc/init.d/networking

Tags: boot, networking

Since this script is used to bring up/down network interfaces. I looked through files under /etc but could not find any script called it.

So how the network interfaces are brought up on booting?

Comment: What is your "init"-process? `systemd` or `upstart`? Type  `ps -p1 | grep systemd && echo systemd || echo upstart` to determine.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/init.d` was the old tree for service configurations used with sysVinit. `upstart` has kept some backwards compatibility and used an entry in `etc/init` to invoke those services not (yet) converted to `upstart`.

Since the introduction of `systemd` those entries seem to be completely obsolete.

Also see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers.